# How put in LinearLayout class which extends GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, glsurfaceview

my question is simple. I have class TouchSurfaceView which extends GLSurfaceView. I want create activity where will three TextViews and Button on bottom and TouchSurfaceView on top, but I don't know how read this in XML layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just reference it usingthe full name (including the package) as if it were any other Vew:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <your.package.TouchSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        />
<!-- etcetera -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You need a constructor that takes AttributeSet as parameter (is used when inflating the xml):

```
public TouchSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
  super(context, attr);
  // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I exactly try this...my package is cz.audiorecenze so I try `<cz.audiorecenze.TouchSurfaceView android:layout_width=....` but logcat writes: `06-05 08:50:52.025: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.audiorecenze/cz.audiorecenze.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class cz.audiorecenze.TouchSurfaceView`

Comment: @west44 it's hard to say more without any code to see, but a likely cause is the lack of the right constructor. See above the updated response.

Comment: Yes you're right. The problem was in costructor which have two parameters (context, AttributeSet) and I have contructor only for (context). Thank's for help ;)